# Pagination class not getting applied in html

Tags: html, angularjs, smart-table

I am having this smart-table in my html, for which 20 rows are getting populated. I have applied pagination to these records, which too is working fine.

My issue is that, the pagination class is not getting applied to the pagination bar. It is just like a link format.

Is some other class getting overlapped with this? I have added the smart-table module in my js too.

```
var app = angular.module('adminApp', ['smart-table', 'ngAnimate',
  'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap'
]);
```

**My table**:

```
<table id="botRecordTable" st-table="display_bot_records" st-safe-src="botData" ng-show="botData" class="table table-bordered table-striped shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" ng-controller="botRulesController">
  <caption style="font-size:0.8rem !important">*BOT Rules.</caption>
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th>CASE NO</th>
      <th st-sort="decision">RULE</th>
      <th st-sort="email">EMAIL</th>
      <th st-sort="dob">DOB</th>
      <th st-sort="gender">GENDER</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr valign="middle" id="{{row.matchPk}}" st-select-row="row" st-select-mode="multiple" ng-repeat="row in display_bot_records">
      <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
      <td>
        <select id="ruleChangeSelect" ng-change="botRuleChanged()" class="custom-select" style="margin-left:0px; width:auto" ng-model="botDecision" ng-options="choice.name for choice in botDecisions">
        </select>
      </td>
      <td ng-bind="row.email"></td>
      <td ng-bind="row.dob"></td>
      <td ng-bind="row.gender"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr style="font-size:0.8rem !important;">
      <td colspan="5" class="text-center">
        <div st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="itemsByPage" st-displayed-pages="5"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

**My pagination**:

[image: here]

**UPDATE**:

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .constant('POSSIBLE_OPTIONS', ['A', 'B', 'C'])
  .controller("MyController", ['POSSIBLE_OPTIONS', function(POSSIBLE_OPTIONS) {
    var ctrl = this;


    ctrl.display_republish_records = [{
        botMainId: "A",
        botSet: "HK64604",
        botNumber: "786443174705883702"
      },
      {
        botMainId: "A",
        botSet: "HK65825",
        botNumber: "595143174706013402"
      },
      {
        botMainId: "A",
        botSet: "HK67383",
        botNumber: "281943174706142702"
      },
      {
        botMainId: "B",
        botSet: "HK72557",
        botNumber: "922443174706654102"
      },
      {
        botMainId: "B",
        botSet: "HK73332",
        botNumber: "724243174706716502"
      },
      {
        botMainId: "A",
        botSet: "HK74025",
        botNumber: "379943174706764502"
      },
      {
        botMainId: "A",
        botSet: "HK74694",
        botNumber: "825843174706807002"
      },
      {
        botMainId: "C",
        botSet: "HK74819",
        botNumber: "563543174706827202"
      },
      {
        botMainId: "C",
        botSet: "HK75964",
        botNumber: "423643174706902802"
      },
      {
        botMainId: "B",
        botSet: "HK76384",
        botNumber: "678043174706923902"
      }
    ];

    ctrl.posibbleOptions = getUniqueValues(ctrl.display_republish_records, 'botMainId')
      .map(optionsMapper);

    ctrl.posibbleOptionsFromConstant = POSSIBLE_OPTIONS
      .map(optionsMapper);

    ctrl.selectionModel = {};

    angular.forEach(ctrl.display_republish_records, function(bot) {
      ctrl.selectionModel[bot.botNumber] = ctrl.posibbleOptions.filter(function(opt) {
        return opt.id === bot.botMainId;
      })[0];
    });

    function optionsMapper(id) {
      return {
        id: id,
        name: id
      }
    }


    function getUniqueValues(array, prop) {
      return [...new Set(array.map(item => item[prop]))];
    }

  }]);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController as $ctrl">
  <hr/>

  <table>

    <tr valign="middle" st-select-row="row" st-select-mode="multiple" ng-repeat="row in $ctrl.display_republish_records track by row.botNumber" ng-attr-id="{{::row.botMainId}}-{{::row.botNumber}}">
      <td>
        <select class="custom-select" style="margin-left:0px" ng-model="$ctrl.selectionModel[row.botNumber]" ng-options="choice.name for choice in $ctrl.posibbleOptions track by choice.id">
          <option value="" hidden readonly="" ng-hide="true"></option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td ng-bind="row.botSet"></td>
      <td ng-bind="row.botNumber"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="font-size:0.8rem !important;">
      <td class="text-center" st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="3">
      </td>
    </tr>


  </table>


  <hr/>

</div>
```

**The scripts I use**:

```
<head>
   <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/app_brand.png"/>
   <meta charset="utf-8"/>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/app.css}" href="../../css/app.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:300" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-animate.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.2/modernizr.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-smart-table/2.1.11/smart-table.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-smart-table/2.1.11/smart-table.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-smart-table/2.1.11/smart-table.min.js.map"></script>
   <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>
   <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: as per their website it seems that they are using bootstrap pagination to design the footer, http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/#section-pagination. Did you tried that?

Comment: Yes @Just Code. I used the same.

Comment: Did you include the bootstrap.css? Can you create demo to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Hi Just code. I have made a example simplified code snippet.

Comment: as far as I know you just need to include some css or bootstrap css, that should work.

Comment: I have updated with the scripts I use too.

Comment: You can also try the Mat paginator.

Comment: I have the option of using smart-table pagination alone Fiza !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smart-table by default applies the pagination of the bootstrap.css classes

Here is the proof of it: http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/#section-pagination.

The main problem of yours is you are using the latest version of bootstrap which is 4.1.0
and smart-table generates the paging by using 3.3.6. I do not know when they can provide the updates to the smart-table. but you can apply this classes to support the box you want.

I have applied the css sections to the demo. Please check here

```js
angular.module("myApp", ['smart-table'])
  .constant('POSSIBLE_OPTIONS', ['A', 'B', 'C'])
  .controller("MyController", ['POSSIBLE_OPTIONS', function(POSSIBLE_OPTIONS) {
  
  
    var ctrl = this;


    ctrl.display_republish_records = [{
        botMainId: "A",
        botSet: "HK64604",
        botNumber: "786443174705883702"
      },
      {
        botMainId: "A",
        botSet: "HK65825",
        botNumber: "595143174706013402"
      },
      {
        botMainId: "A",
        botSet: "HK67383",
        botNumber: "281943174706142702"
      },
      {
        botMainId: "B",
        botSet: "HK72557",
        botNumber: "922443174706654102"
      },
      {
        botMainId: "B",
        botSet: "HK73332",
        botNumber: "7242431747s6716502"
      },
      {
        botMainId: "A",
        botSet: "HK74025",
        botNumber: "3799431747067e4502"
      },
      {
        botMainId: "A",
        botSet: "HK74694",
        botNumber: "82584317g706807002"
      },
      {
        botMainId: "C",
        botSet: "HK74819",
        botNumber: "56354317470x6827202"
      },
      {
        botMainId: "C",
        botSet: "HK75964",
        botNumber: "42364317470cxv6902802"
      },
      {
        botMainId: "B",
        botSet: "HK76384",
        botNumber: "678043174706xcv923902"
      },
      {
        botMainId: "B",
        botSet: "HK76384",
        botNumber: "6780431747069df23902"
      },
      {
        botMainId: "B",
        botSet: "HK76384",
        botNumber: "6780431747069ewr23902"
      },
      {
        botMainId: "B",
        botSet: "HK76384",
        botNumber: "67804317470sdf6923902"
      },
      {
        botMainId: "B",
        botSet: "HK76384",
        botNumber: "67804317470s6923902"
      },
      {
        botMainId: "B",
        botSet: "HK76384",
        botNumber: "67804317470vb6923902"
      },
      {
        botMainId: "B",
        botSet: "HK76384",
        botNumber: "6780431747sdf06923902"
      },
      {
        botMainId: "B",
        botSet: "HK76384",
        botNumber: "67804317470sd6923902"
      },
      {
        botMainId: "B",
        botSet: "HK76384",
        botNumber: "67804317wer4706923902"
      },
      {
        botMainId: "B",
        botSet: "HK76384",
        botNumber: "678043174706sd923902"
      },
      {
        botMainId: "B",
        botSet: "HK76384",
        botNumber: "67804317470a923902"
      }
    ];

    ctrl.posibbleOptions = getUniqueValues(ctrl.display_republish_records, 'botMainId')
      .map(optionsMapper);

    ctrl.posibbleOptionsFromConstant = POSSIBLE_OPTIONS
      .map(optionsMapper);

    ctrl.selectionModel = {};
    ctrl.itemsByPage = 5;

    angular.forEach(ctrl.display_republish_records, function(bot) {
      ctrl.selectionModel[bot.botNumber] = ctrl.posibbleOptions.filter(function(opt) {
        return opt.id === bot.botMainId;
      })[0];
    });

    function optionsMapper(id) {
      return {
        id: id,
        name: id
      }
    }


    function getUniqueValues(array, prop) {
      return [...new Set(array.map(item => item[prop]))];
    }

  }]);
```

```css
.pagination > li > a,
.pagination > li > span {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #337ab7;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.pagination > li:first-child > a,
.pagination > li:first-child > span {
  margin-left: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
.pagination > li:last-child > a,
.pagination > li:last-child > span {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
.pagination > li > a:hover,
.pagination > li > span:hover,
.pagination > li > a:focus,
.pagination > li > span:focus {
  z-index: 2;
  color: #23527c;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-color: #ddd;
}
.pagination > .active > a,
.pagination > .active > span,
.pagination > .active > a:hover,
.pagination > .active > span:hover,
.pagination > .active > a:focus,
.pagination > .active > span:focus {
  z-index: 3;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #337ab7;
  border-color: #337ab7;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-smart-table/2.1.11/smart-table.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController as $ctrl">
  <hr/>

  <table st-table="$ctrl.display_republish_records" class="table table-striped">

    <tr valign="middle" st-select-row="row" st-select-mode="multiple" ng-repeat="row in $ctrl.display_republish_records track by row.botNumber" ng-attr-id="{{::row.botMainId}}-{{::row.botNumber}}">
      <td>
        <select class="custom-select" style="margin-left:0px" ng-model="$ctrl.selectionModel[row.botNumber]" ng-options="choice.name for choice in $ctrl.posibbleOptions track by choice.id">
          <option value="" hidden readonly="" ng-hide="true"></option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td ng-bind="row.botSet"></td>
      <td ng-bind="row.botNumber"></td>
    </tr>    <tfoot>
      <tr>
  <td class="text-center" st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="10" colspan="4">
  </td>
 </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>


  <hr/>

</div>
```

Comment: That's much helpful info @Just Code. !! So, the pagination UI is yet to be developed for the current bootstrap version I'm using. That was why it wasn't working. Cool. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the 50 rep to comment yet...

Have you tried opening the console (F12) and checking the styles tab to see which styles are being applied and from which stylesheet(s)? That'll probably give you the most insight. It is likely that the bootstrap styles are overriding the ones you added. If you want custom styles to override the bootstrap ones, you'd have to add your stylesheet after the bootstrap stylesheet is loaded, and it's probably loading with the smart table module.

Due to the cascading nature of styles, if you add styles to the pagination in your own stylesheet and then bootstrap loads and adds styles, they'll override your styles.

Comment: Hi Jordan. I have tried doing your recommendation. My other functionalities doesn't seem to work if I do so.